# Using google app engine as an smtp server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We're looking to use google to send out emails, it looks like this can be done through google app engine pretty easily: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail

However what I'm wondering is, can we use the google app as a smtp server / gateway, so that we can put in an address from the app into where we currently send out messages, and the app will take them and submit them to google to send through their api?

Comment: Good thing no one downvoted this question. In my case I asked the same question then I get downvoted many times. And closed my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can not be done as GAE does not support inbound socket connections, which are needed for SMTP.

Also, sending mails from GAE has numerous restrictions: mail can be only sent as originating from admin/developer account or currently logged-in user (only via Google Accounts, not federated login).

Comment: Good thing no one down voted this question. In my case I asked the same question then I get down voted many times. And closed my question.